# C++ or macro magic to generate method and forward arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I would like to create a magical macro, or anything, that would generate a something like this:

```
MAGICAL_MACRO(return_type, method_name, ...)
```

should work like this:

```
MAGICAL_MACRO(void, Foo, int a, int b)
```

->

```
virtual void Foo(int a, int b) 
{
    _obj->Foo(a, b);
}
```

Is this possible? I am afraid it is not.

Comment: How would you forward the arguments without the types?

Comment: No, that is NOT the same question. I do know how to use perfect forwarding, that is NOT the question, please read the question carefully.

Comment: The 2nd duplicate may help you better.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I don't think it is a duplicate. He want's not only to forward the arguments which would be easy with a variadic macro. He also want to use the names of the macro for passing and the type + name in the definition.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512630/passing-variadic-template-arguments-to-a-variadic-function then?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not really, this doesn't seem limited to what C variadics allow.

Comment: No, template methods can not be virtual. This questions is not about c++11 forwarding.

Comment: For the record, your proposed syntax is brittle: `MAGICAL_MACRO(void, Foo, std::map<int, int> a)` would be impossible to handle.

Comment: That's just a rough idea, I am open to any suggestions, see below @Angew's answer

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use macros in order to create variable or function declarations. There might be far more elegant ways to achieve the same thing. What is the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: 1. To annotate all the methods, in order to automagically generate python wrappers to these specific classes
2. Prevent calling these methods directly, since they have some very specific behavior that has to be strongly distinguished from any other method 
3. Being able to alter the behavior of these method calls automatically, without having to modify all the methods. Eg. I would like to automatically create a log of these method calls, with all the arguments, and play back all the calls for debug purposes.

Answer (score 6):

Two questions: Are you open to a slightly different syntax for the arguments of `MAGIC_MACRO`? And can you use the [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) header-only library?

If both answers are "yes", I have a solution for you:

```
#define MAGICAL_MACRO(Type, Name, ...) \
  virtual Type Name(MAGICAL_GENERATE_PARAMETERS(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))) {\
    _obj->Name(MAGICAL_GENERATE_ARGUMENTS(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))); \
  }

#define MAGICAL_GENERATE_PARAMETERS(Args) \
  BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(MAGICAL_MAKE_PARAMETER, %%, Args))

#define MAGICAL_GENERATE_ARGUMENTS(Args) \
  BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(MAGICAL_MAKE_ARGUMENT, %%, Args))

#define MAGICAL_MAKE_PARAMETER(s, Unused, Arg) \
  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, Arg) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, Arg)

#define MAGICAL_MAKE_ARGUMENT(s, Unused, Arg) \
  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, Arg)
```

Usage looks like this:

```
MAGICAL_MACRO(void, Foo, (int, a), (int, b))
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/225c375e43a9ee39)

The `%%` used in the macro definitions is just my way of indicating "this value is not used." You could use pretty much anything else there (unless it contains a comma).

The above solution will work as long as the types involved are not spelled with a comma. If they are, introduce a type alias for them (`typedef` or `using`). Note that it *is* possible to get around this within the preprocessor magic itself, but it complicates already ugly code.

Comment: Yes, that could be an option, however I am against using boost :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind changing the syntax for the macro arguments, you could use following trick which abuses declaration syntax:

```
#define MAGICAL_MACRO(return_type, method_name, ...) \
    virtual return_type method_name(__VA_ARGS__)
    { \
        _obj->method_name(__VA_ARGS__); \
    }

MAGICAL_MACRO(void, foo, int(a), int(b))
```

That will expand to:

```
virtual void foo(int(a), int(b))
{
    _obj->foo(int(a), int(b));
}
```

Where `void func(int(a), int(b))` is completely equivalent to `void func(int a, int b)`.

The extra casts (or constructor calls depending on argument types) are ugly, but both GCC and Clang (with `-O0`) seem to ignore them not only for primitive types/PODs, but also for non-POD classes even if their copy constructors have side effects:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int x;
    A(int value) : x(value) {}
    A(const A &o)
    {
        x = o.x;
        std::cout << "copy";
    }
};

void func(A a)
{
    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
}

void func1(A a)
{
    func(a);
}
void func2(A a)
{
    func(A(a));
}

int main()
{
    func1(1); // prints `copy1`
    func2(2); // prints `copy2`
}
```

Comment: This will actually call the copy constructor of the arguments, that should affect the generated code, since I can do anything in the copy constructor.

Comment: @IstvánCsanády If I remember correctly, regardless of side effects of a copy constructor, compiler is allowed to elide it.

Comment: Very clever ! -

Answer (score 4):

The code below is working for what you've asked for with up to 1024 arguments and **without** using additional stuff like boost. It defines an `EVAL(...)` and also a `MAP(m, first, ...)` macro to do recursion and to use for each iteration the macro `m` with the next parameter `first`.

It is mostly copied from [C Pre-Processor Magic](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic). It is also great explained there. You can also download these helper macros like `EVAL(...)` at this [git repository](https://github.com/18sg/uSHET/blob/master/lib/cpp_magic.h), there are also a lot of explanation in the actual code. It is variadic so it takes the number of arguments you want.

But I changed the `FIRST` and the `SECOND` macro as it uses a Gnu extension like it is in the source I've copied it from.

To split arguments like `int a` into `int` and `a` I used [this answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23400746/8051589).

Your macro will be:

```
#define MAGICAL_MACRO(return_type, method_name, ...) \
   virtual return_type method_name(__VA_ARGS__) \
   { \
      return _obj->method_name(EVAL(MAP(TYPE_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))); \
   }
```

Examples and limitations:

```
MAGICAL_MACRO(void, FOO, int a, double b, char c);
--> virtual void FOO(int a, double b, char c) { return _obj->FOO(a , b , c); };

MAGICAL_MACRO(int, FOO, int a, double b, char c);
-->  virtual int FOO(int a, double b, char c) { return _obj->FOO(a , b , c); } ;

MAGICAL_MACRO(void, FOO, int* a, double* b, char* c);
--> virtual void* FOO(int* a, double* b, char* c) { return _obj->FOO(* a , * b , * c); };
/* maybe not what you want: pointer are dereferenced */
```

All the other macros needed, note that type splitting need to be defined per macro here:

```
/* Define all types here */
#define SPLIT_int int COMMA
#define SPLIT_char char COMMA
#define SPLIT_float float COMMA
#define SPLIT_double double COMMA

#define FIRST_(a, ...) a
#define SECOND_(a, b, ...) b

#define FIRST(...) FIRST_(__VA_ARGS__,)
#define SECOND(...) SECOND_(__VA_ARGS__,)

#define EMPTY()

#define EVAL(...) EVAL1024(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EVAL1024(...) EVAL512(EVAL512(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL512(...) EVAL256(EVAL256(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL256(...) EVAL128(EVAL128(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL128(...) EVAL64(EVAL64(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL64(...) EVAL32(EVAL32(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL32(...) EVAL16(EVAL16(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL16(...) EVAL8(EVAL8(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL8(...) EVAL4(EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL2(EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL1(EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define DEFER1(m) m EMPTY()
#define DEFER2(m) m EMPTY EMPTY()()
#define DEFER3(m) m EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY()()()
#define DEFER4(m) m EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY()()()()

#define IS_PROBE(...) SECOND(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
#define PROBE() ~, 1

#define CAT(a,b) a ## b

#define NOT(x) IS_PROBE(CAT(_NOT_, x))
#define _NOT_0 PROBE()

#define BOOL(x) NOT(NOT(x))

#define IF_ELSE(condition) _IF_ELSE(BOOL(condition))
#define _IF_ELSE(condition) CAT(_IF_, condition)

#define _IF_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ _IF_1_ELSE
#define _IF_0(...)             _IF_0_ELSE

#define _IF_1_ELSE(...)
#define _IF_0_ELSE(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define HAS_ARGS(...) BOOL(FIRST(_END_OF_ARGUMENTS_ __VA_ARGS__)())
#define _END_OF_ARGUMENTS_() 0

#define MAP(m, first, ...)           \
  m(first)                           \
  IF_ELSE(HAS_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(    \
    COMMA DEFER2(_MAP)()(m, __VA_ARGS__)   \
  )(                                 \
    /* Do nothing, just terminate */ \
  )
#define _MAP() MAP


#define COMMA ,

#define CALL(A,B) A B
#define SPLIT(D) EVAL1(CAT(SPLIT_, D))
#define TYPE_NAME(D) CALL(SECOND,(SPLIT(D)))
```

Comment: Wow! But this will require to define SPLIT macros to every type, right?

Comment: @IstvánCsanády: Yeah right if you want to use that feature to call it like `MAGICAL_MACRO(void, FOO, int a, double b, char`); and not `MAGICAL_MACRO(void, FOO, int, a, double, b, char, c);` Also you may want to return a value if teh type is not void. I will integrate that too and extend my answer.

Comment: @IstvánCsanády: Now the macro also recognizes, if you want to return a value, type other than void. If so it uses a return statement. But there are limitations as void causes trouble. Maybe I will find a solution for that. Also the handling of pointer in the arguments list is not what you want?

Comment: You are missing semicolon after return statement.

Comment: And you don't need to switch on return type. You can use `return foo();` in `void` method if `foo` also returns `void`.

Comment: @Zereges: Thank you, now the macro easily always return something and added the missing semicolon.

Comment: @IstvánCsanády: Does any answer here meets your requirements or is here no answer that's working for you?